# Lowest rated player(s) who earned a GM norm

Tags: history, fide, rating, grandmaster, norm

Who had the lowest rating when they earned at least one GM norm?

Comment: these zonal tournaments give GM norms. probably some african zonal?

Comment: define lowest rating (does it mean FIDE?) and doesnt it have to be 2600, since thats the level to get a GM norm?

Comment: @DialFrost anyone can get a torment proformance rating of 2600 regardless of their rating.

Comment: FIDE has a page showing title norm application at https://ratings.fide.com/title_norms.phtml?title=GM&country=.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think he holds the record but IM Yochanan [Afek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yochanan_Afek) was rated 2329 (and already 50 years old !) when he secured his first GM-norm by winning the [Paris City Championship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_City_Chess_Championship) in 2002.

Putting aside GM-norms from special tournaments (Zonals or Youth Championships), I suspect only underrated youngsters might have achieved a norm while being rated lower.